# How to Use fillPage in Shiny Dashboard

Tags: css, r, ggplot2, shiny, shinydashboard

I cannot make a map appear as a full screen with Shiny in R. Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks.

I have played around with numerous variations of height = "100%" and height = "auto" in both the ui and server sides. These have been tried in the fillPage, fillCol, fillRow, outputPlot and renderPlot functions.

I can force something if I use height = "400px" etc but that doesn't provide anything in general when moving the dashboard from say a laptop screen to something a bit bigger, etc.

I have provided the code for a simplified version. It contains the css styles that I have in my 'real' version as my understanding is that css may also affect the R code.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "SOS"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    br()
  ),
  dashboardBody(tags$body(tags$style(HTML('
                              /* logo */
                                          .skin-blue .main-header .logo {
                                          background-color: #0a22d8;
                                          }

                                          /* logo when hovered */
                                          .skin-blue .main-header .logo:hover {
                                          background-color: #8390ef;
                                          }

                                          /* navbar (rest of the header) */
                                          .skin-blue .main-header .navbar {
                                          background-color: #0a22d8;
                                          }        

                                          /* main sidebar */
                                          .skin-blue .main-sidebar {
                                          background-color: #0a22d8;
                                          }

                                          /* active selected tab in the sidebarmenu */
                                          .skin-blue .main-sidebar .sidebar .sidebar-menu .active a{
                                          background-color: #ff0000;
                                          }

                                          /* other links in the sidebarmenu */
                                          .skin-blue .main-sidebar .sidebar .sidebar-menu a{
                                          background-color: #00ff00;
                                          color: #000000;
                                          }

                                          /* other links in the sidebarmenu when hovered */
                                          .skin-blue .main-sidebar .sidebar .sidebar-menu a:hover{
                                          background-color: #ff69b4;
                                          }
                                          /* toggle button when hovered  */                    
                                          .skin-blue .main-header .navbar .sidebar-toggle:hover{
                                          background-color: #8390ef;
                                          }

                                         /* my atmpt background   */
                                          .skin-blue .content {background-color: #8390ef;}'))),
                tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                            tabPanel("Help", 
                                     br(),
                                     fillPage(
                                       fillRow(plotOutput("my_map"))
                                     )))))

server <- function(input, output, session){

  output$my_map <- renderPlot({
    wrld <- map_data("world")

    ggplot(wrld,  color = "white") +
      geom_polygon(aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) +
      coord_fixed(1.3) +
      guides(fill = F)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

can you please give below property (instead of div you can use your class)

```
 div{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    }
```

Comment: thnx... but where do i place that? I tried inserting in the HTML function just after the /* logo */ comment but nothing changed.